# How to store matrix list data in recursive python function?

Tags: python, list, variables, recursion

I am trying to solve the N_Queen problem with recursive function. My codes are shown below. The problemm is that I cannot store the acceptable solution in a list. I can see that all the right answers appeared while debuging, but those answers cannot store in a list outside the recursive function. I hope the acceptable solution could be stored in a list and keep on recursion for the next right answer. But the appended solution are always changing.

By importing copy and deepcopy, I have solved the problem, yet it is still confusing. It seems that others can store pure list result without deepcopy, but my matrix list is unacceptable.

THX.

```
def NQueens(self, n: int) -> int:
    res = []
    board = [['.' for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]

    def backtrack(board,row):
        if row == n:
            res.append(board) # **this is the confusing part**
            return
        for col in range(n):
            if not isvalid(board,row,col):
                continue
            board[row][col] = 'Q'
            backtrack(board,row+1)
            board[row][col] = '.'

    def isvalid(board,row,col):
        for i in range(row):
            if board[i][col] == 'Q':
                return False
        for i in range(1,row+1):
            if col - i >= 0 and board[row - i][col - i] == 'Q':
                return False
        for i in range(1,row+1):
            if col + i < n and board[row - i][col + i] == 'Q':
                return False
        return True

    backtrack(board,0)
    return res
```

Comment: Note: since you know that there is exactly one queen per column, you can store the solution as a simple list rather than a list of lists. For instance, if n=5, as `[0, 2, 4, 1, 3]` instead of `['..Q..', '....Q', '.Q...', '...Q.', 'Q....']`

Comment: Good point. It seems that this simple list can be appended to the res as solution. I just wonder why the matrix solution cannot work. (deepcopy could make it work though)

Comment: It can work. In theory there is not much difference between the two representations. You just have to be very careful. And it's easier to be careful with a single list than with a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that you can't save it, the problem is that after saving it you change the values of the `board` and they are linked so they both change so, when you finally return `res`, you end up returning the last state of `board` x times over, x beeing the times you appended it

I currently don't know hot to solve this but when i find out i'll edit or comment on this

Answer (score 0):

i finally found the problem, sorry for the wait.

In the line `board[row][col] = '.'` there were no conditions for that, what i mean is that it will alwas happen so when you put a queen after backtracking you'll remove it without exceptions.

I changed it so it will make a `return true` statement if achived to place all the queens so when backtracking it will not delete them if it found a solution.

I'll leave the working code, commenting what i changed, here:

```
def NQueens(n: int) -> int:
    board = [['.' for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]

    def backtrack(board,row):
        #If all queens are placed then return true
        if row >= n:
            return True
        
        for col in range(n):
            #if it is valid place the queen and try to place the next queen on the next row
            if isvalid(board,row,col):
                board[row][col] = 'Q'
                if backtrack(board,row+1) == True:
                    return True
                
                #if placing the queen was not the way to the solution remove the queen
                board[row][col] = '.'
        #if the queen can't be placed in any column in this row return false 
        return False

    def isvalid(board,row,col):
        for i in range(row):
            if board[i][col] == 'Q':
                return False
        for i in range(1,row+1):
            if col - i >= 0 and board[row - i][col - i] == 'Q':
                return False
        for i in range(1,row+1):
            if col + i < n and board[row - i][col + i] == 'Q':
                return False
        return True

    backtrack(board,0)
    return board #directly return board, res was innecesary
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I runned your code with n = 4 and the result is one acceptable solution. The actual result should be 2 acceptable solutions.
I agree with you that my res just return the final state of the board, which is also the confusing part for me.

Comment: @BillZh Ahh.. now i understand XD. Here is a solution you can see and compare it:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/n-queen-problem-backtracking-3/